# Elements (equation, pictures,...) falling out of the paper

Tags: latex

I am preparing a paper for **International Journal of Ad Hoc and Ubiquitous Computing**. Latex template of this journal provided in http://www.inderscience.com/info/inauthors/author_templates.php (two column).
However I have some problem with this:
In some cases likes pictures, diagrams, tables and specially equations, my equation did not fit in its column and latex put them outside of the box borders.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Using this template put many of my figures out of the paper box, any Helps appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This question is far too broad to answer with specific solutions... For all these different problems exist different solutions.

In general I can say (if you are using `multicols`... I take that for granted):

- For pictures and tables the general width of one column is calculated by `\dimexpr\columnwidth-\columnsep\relax` so you should define a new length `\cwidth` that you can use as correct width for things you want to insert.

  ```
  \newlength{\cwidth}
  \setlength{\cwdith}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\columnsep\relax}
  ```

  This will define a new width that's exactely the width of your column. To use it with, for example `\includegraphics`, do this now:

  ```
  \includegraphics[width=\cwidth]{yourpicture}
  ```

  And of course don't forget `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` else you will still have an indent on graphics because graphics normally are new paragraphs.
- For equations you should generally have a look at `multline` from `amsmath`.

Comment: I used this: 

\begin{figure}[h!]\centering \includegraphics[width=2cm]{pic1.eps}\end{figure}

However it does not work

Comment: @H.Aqjn Never use a figure-environment if you don't need it. As rule of thumb: Never use figure if you use [h!] or [H] with it, there are better ways to do it(for captions in this case, look up `\captionof`). And I will update my answer to show this example.